# log4js-node mask sensitive details while logging

Tags: node.js, logging, log4js-node

Could anyone help on masking sensitive fields using [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) in node? Found similar filters in winston logger but if something similar is available in log4js, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found some workaround.

For example, if you want to have log in pattern: "%r %p %c %m%n"  where
%r - time, %p - log level, %c - log category, %m - log data, %n - newline.

And if you want to mask some sensitive data in %m, you can do it in this way:

Add layout to your appender:

```
    layout: {
         type    : "pattern",
         pattern : "%r %p %c {%x{body}}%n",
         tokens: {
             body : function() {
                 var msg = arguments[0].data[0];
                 return maskSensitiveData(msg);
             }
         }
     }
```

and then implement function

```
var maskSensitiveData = function(msg) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: any idea how to mask data in winston ?